# Remote Access Exception Java Read time out

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8

I am getting this exception:
COULD NOT ACCESS HTTP INVOKER REMOTE SERVICE AT [service URL]; nested exception is Java.net.SocketTimeOutException: Read Time out.

I need a solution for this. I went into the XML file to increase the readTimeout while that service URL is called but it says no such property

I am new to spring boot. Can someone please let me know the fix for it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079273/java-net-sockettimeoutexception-read-timed-out-under-tomcat Might help

Comment: @karthikeyan thank you I will refer it

Comment: @karthikeyan Vaithimgam tried what said on other blog. It is not working . Plz could u help

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the read TIMEOUT allowed, typical TIMEOUT length is between 3000 - 7000 milliseconds (3 - 7 seconds)

   - time limit is not more than 5 minutes (no longer than 300000)
2. You may also want to troubleshoot connection issues on your network, to ensure speed is optimized

Comment: can you please tell me where to add the timeout?